# how to run webdriver-manager on windows server 2012 r2?

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor, windows-server-2012, webdriver-manager

I am trying to run 'webdriver-manager start ' selenium on a windows server 2012 r2 box but getting this error:

```
Selenium standalone has exited with code 1
```

In windows 7 it works fine?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the setup was same for Windows 7 or Windows Server 2012 R2.

Please make sure:

1. You did not miss any steps.
2. The server is not started in some other instance.

Please copy the entire logs in case the above do not help

Answer (score 0):

Have you got java installed? I'm currently unable to run because I need Java and it's not installed by default.